# Symfony 6 Windows Error system library:fopen:No such process

Tags: reactjs, jwt, key-pair, symfony6

I installed on Symfony 6 (php8.1) the package jwt-auth with the command : composer require jwt-auth.

And when I want to generate the keypair with : php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair

I have the following error : system library:fopen:No such process.
The extension openssl is running in my php.ini.
I am trying to use the commands :

openssl genpkey -out config/jwt/private.pem -aes256 -algorithm rsa -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:4096

openssl pkey -in config/jwt/private.pem -out config/jwt/public.pem -pubout

But there is infinite loading.

Does anyone know how to do it?

I want to make a login form with React JS,
Do you know any other way to recover the encrypted passwords from the database?

Thank you in advance for your answers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved !

If you have the same problem (openSSL Windows 10), I give you the issue.

So you need to go on this link : https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html
And download openSSL (down a little on the page).

Then, open a new Terminal or git bash and do this command :
set OPENSSL_CONF=LOCATION_OF_SSL_INSTALL\bin\openssl.cfg

Now you can generate keys with this command in your Symfony project :
php bin/console lexik:jwt:generate-keypair

It works for me